# Install specific version of unison with homebrew

Tags: docker, ocaml, unison

I'm using `docker-sync` and unison in a docker env.

In my `docker-sync.yml` I am using the following version of the container

```
 eugenmayer/unison:2.51.2.1'
```

And as advised on the website I installed unison on local with homebrew, unfortunately, the following version is installed `2.51.2` with `ocaml 0.4.9.0` But the docker contain used in docker sync is using the same version `2.51.2`  but with `ocaml 4.07.0` which lead to an error that make docker-sync faile.

Unfortunately, I don't succeed to find how to downgrade the version of unison to have a matching version of `ocaml` from homebrew. Any hint or idea ?

Comment: Any advice from anyone on this question ? Still can't figured it out...